# Creating chains of certificates

Tags: ssl

I've managed to create a certificate from this line in `cmd`

```
openssl req -config openssl.conf -new -x509 -days 1001 -key keys/ca.key -out certs/ca.cer
```

This will create a root certificate, named `ca.cer`. For my mobile application I want to create a new certificate from this root certificate and generate a keystore from this "child" certificate. How can I do so in `openssl` under windows? I've read this [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/126121/how-to-create-my-own-certificate-chain), but i didnt understand much of it.

Thanks in advance.